# How to determine if / ensure that a second-hand storage device is safe to use?

Tags: security, ssd, malware-detection

I am going to buy a SSD from someone who works in the same company, but even so is a complete stranger to me.

Maybe I am a little paranoid, but is there a way to check if it is safe to use?

Or is it stupid to assume that someone messed with it in a way to harm me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is safe to use but if you think that he has done something to harm you just format it before using, using the `secure erase`.

Comment: Thank you for that answer. I going to wait some time (since the post is barely 15 mins old), but if there won't be any different opinions on this topic, I will accept your answer.

Comment: see this also https://www.google.co.in/search?q=how+to+remove+virus+from+ssd+completely&oq=how+to+remove+virus+from+ssd+completely&aqs=chrome..69i57.19992j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8

Comment: secure erase is not a tool, its a command that you can give your drive

Comment: thanks but i think its an utility software. and there is a tool also eraser.

Comment: @AndroidRookie While utility software programs exists which erase a drive by writing all sectors, "Journeyman Geek" is correct in pointing out that Secure Erase is (also) a command which can be sent to the SSD. This SSD command is actually the preferred way to erase an SSD since (1) it will probably be faster and (2) may yield potential performance improvements. A google search should yield articles with more info. Here is a [link to one example:](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2088341/how-to-restore-your-ssd-to-peak-performance.html) (Apologies for the annoying ads).